# Link not displayed correctly

Tags: hyperlink, ascii, haml

In my haml code,  I have entered the following link

```
.download_section
  %a{href:"https://mailto:xxxx@gmail.com"}
    %b
      Work wth us
```

However, in the display, after checking the link, I realised that only the 'gmail' is shown

[image]

I tried to change the @ and the colon to ASCII code, but it didn't seem to help

```
.download_section
  %a{href:"https://mailto&#58;xxxx&#64;gmail.com"}
   %b
    Work wth us
```

Can anyone advise me how I can make the link appear as it is?

Comment: You might want to double-check how `mailto` works: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto

Comment: What do you mean 'in display' ? I tried ur code. if i click on it takes me to https://mailto:xxxx@gmail.com. Not sure i understand what you want here?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try something like:

```
.download_section
  %a{:href => "mailto:xxxx@gmail.com"} Work with us
```

The link might be getting confused by the `https://` part in the code from your question. *(See more information about [mailto links here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailto).)*